# HipHop Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS

Tags: php, facebook, hiphop, hhvm

I am trying to make a framework work for HHVM, but I am running into this weird error that only occurs in Hip-Hop HHVM. The same error only occurs in versions of PHP 5.2 and lower. The full error is

```
HipHop Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /var/www/www.unbiasly.com/libraries/prodigyview/data/PVStaticPatterns.php on line 116
```

Line 116 is this class here:

https://github.com/ProdigyView/ProdigyView-Core/blob/master/data/PVStaticPatterns.php#L116

Is there something different about the Reflection class in HHVM? Is it running on an older version of PHP? Can't make heads or tails of the T_CLASS error.

Comment: It looks like a conflict with the "class" keyword

Comment: Are you saying $method -> class cannot be used? Even if it's part of the reflection's method object?

Comment: Well, Hip-hop compiles PHP to C, right? Perhaps it's not smart enough to detect the property, and thinks it's a class definition starting

Comment: Well, it appear that is it. I change $method -> class to $method -> {'class'} as a fix....seems kinda ridiculous that a method would have to be called that way.

Comment: Also, you might want to add that as answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. `class` is a context sensitive keyword and the space before it makes us think you're making a class. I opened an issue: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues/873

Comment: I should have updated this, I also made a bug for this before: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/issues/833

Comment: This is bug is fixed in the latest HHVM release.